# ServiceNow XML export gives UIDs instead of values

Tags: servicenow

I am exporting data from ServiceNow regularly.  Initially I was using CSV output, with an export URL like this:

`https://mysnow.service-now.com/incident_list.do?CSV&sysparm_query=ORDERBYsys_id%5esys_idSTARTSWITH0&sysparm_default_export_fields=all`

Various problems of scale forced a change to XML.  I figured I could just change the output format and call it a day:

`https://mysnow.service-now.com/incident_list.do?XML&sysparm_query=ORDERBYsys_id%5esys_idSTARTSWITH0&sysparm_default_export_fields=all`

Oddly, there is a difference in data.  In the CSV output, values that would be expected to be names-- "closed_by", for example, has "John Smith".  In the XML output, though, those are UIDs such as:

`<closed_by>932ab9381a050510fc3d54e8224bcbc1</closed_by>`

Why is that the case?  I want the names, not the UIDs.  How do I get it to produce the names in the XML output?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `&sysparm_display_value=true`